# getting error in EChart library [__NSCFString value]

Tags: ios, charts

I am using [EChart](https://github.com/zhuhuihuihui/EChart) library, trying to make bar chart in iPad. I did make everything like in demo project but getting error :

```
-[__NSCFString value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8bba220
2014-08-18 08:28:44.684 STAT_V2_iPAD[19187:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8bba220'
```

and here is the error code after debugging :

```
/** The highest value among the whole chart*/
- (EColumnDataModel *) highestValueEColumnChart:(EColumnChart *) eColumnChart{
    EColumnDataModel *maxDataModel = nil;

     float maxValue = -FLT_MIN;
     NSLog(@"After FLT_MIN : %.f",FLT_MIN);

     for (EColumnDataModel *dataModel in MergedArr)
     {
     NSLog(@"Data.Value = %f",dataModel.value);
     if (dataModel.value > maxValue)
     {
     NSLog(@"inside ifd");
     maxValue = dataModel.value;
     maxDataModel = dataModel;
     }
     }
     NSLog(@"Finished MAX %.f",maxDataModel.value);

    return maxDataModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your dataModel holds `NSString` instead of `EColumnDataModel` . Below answer will prevent the crash but you need to find how string takes place?

```
 -(EColumnDataModel *) highestValueEColumnChart:(EColumnChart *) eColumnChart{
        EColumnDataModel *maxDataModel = nil;

         float maxValue = -FLT_MIN;
     NSLog(@"After FLT_MIN : %.f",FLT_MIN);

     for (EColumnDataModel *dataModel in MergedArr)
     {
if([dataModel isKindOfClass:[EColumnDataModel class]]){
     NSLog(@"Data.Value = %f",dataModel.value);
     if (dataModel.value > maxValue)
     {
     NSLog(@"inside ifd");
     maxValue = dataModel.value;
     maxDataModel = dataModel;
     }
}
     }
     NSLog(@"Finished MAX %.f",maxDataModel.value);

    return maxDataModel;
}
```

Comment: how can I convert MergedArr to EColumnDataModel ? because it is gives me nil all time ...

Comment: NSLog(@"Finished MAX %d", MergedArr.count); use it to check whether you have object in your array

Comment: I know it contain float value and 8 object

Comment: you can not keep primitive  values into array

Comment: what do you think the solution for this ?